# I can't seem to figure out how to fix an error in my ksoap2 android code

Tags: java, android, solution

```
       public void onClick(View button_one) 
           {
              new Thread(new Runnable() 
                 {
                    public void run() 
                       {
                          final SoapObject request;
                          request.post(new Runnable() // THIS post over HERE !!!
                             {
                                public void run() 
                                   {
                                      request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                                   }
                             });
                       }
                }).start();
           }
```

**Problem:** Post is underlined and solution by eclipse is below, but that spawns alien amount of new problems

```
-The method post(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type SoapObject
```

Also, is this gonna run successfully ? Or am I doing something wrong ? ???

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear: your `request` variable doesn't have a `post()` method. Looks like you are trying to use [View.post()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29), which runs code on UI thread. This isn't necessary here, just create your object like this:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
```

Comment: ... My app crashes everytime any soap method is called, i can't finish withought threads..., what are you trying to tell me here...